# Type 'User | null' is not assignable to type 'null'

Tags: typescript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

While setting up my AuthContext I always run into the following TypeScript error:

```
Type '{ currentUser: User | null; login: (email: string, password: string) => Promise<UserCredential>; signup: (email: string, password: string) => Promise<UserCredential>; logout: () => Promise<...>; }' is not assignable to type '{ currentUser: null; login: (email: string, password: string) => void; signup: (email: string, password: string) => void; logout: () => void; }'.
   Types of property 'currentUser' are incompatible.
    Type 'User | null' is not assignable to type 'null'.
      Type 'User' is not assignable to type 'null'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(307, 9): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps<{ currentUser: null; login: (email: string, password: string) => void; signup: (email: string, password: string) => void; logout: () => void; }>'
```

The code in my AuthContext.tsx looks like this:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect, useRef} from "react";
import { auth, db } from "@inter/helpers/firebase";
import {
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  User
} from "firebase/auth";
import { doc, setDoc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const AuthContext = React.createContext({
    currentUser: null,
    login: (email:string, password:string) => {},
    signup: (email:string, password:string) => {},
    logout: () => {},
});

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }:{children:React.ReactNode}) {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<null | User>(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    function signup(email:string, password:string) {
        return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    }

    function login(email:string, password:string) {
        return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    }

    function logout() {
        return signOut(auth);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
            setCurrentUser(user);
            setLoading(false);
        });
        return unsubscribe;
    }, []);

    const value = {
        currentUser,
        login,
        signup,
        logout,
    };

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {!loading && children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

Comment: You need to provide an explicit type when you create the context, otherwise currentUser is inferred to _always_ need to be null.

Comment: In other words, see how your currentUser context property is typed to only allow a null value?  `currentUser: null`